# Add Parameters to Basic Post Command in R

Tags: r, curl, markdown

I came across [this service](http://documentup.com/#themes) that will format my local markdown files rather nicely.  Per the example, it is easy to get a nicely formatted response with a sample curl command.

What I am looking to do is utilize some of the options available, namely the version and "name" parameters. How would I go about structuring the curl command?  Below are the code samples that I have used within R.

This code works nicely, but lacks the specified options:

```
doc.up <- "curl -X POST --data-urlencode content@test-markdown.md  \ http://documentup.com/compiled > index.html"
system(doc.up)
```

I tried to specify the name option, but no dice:

```
doc.up <- "curl -X POST --data-urlencode name@mynamevar content@test-markdown.md  \ http://documentup.com/compiled > index.html"
system(doc.up)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  Per some of the suggestions below, I have attempted a few ways to use `Rcurl` and `HTTR`.  I am using the default Markdown template within Rstudio, but for completeness sake, I saved it as test-markdown.Rmd and compiled it test-markdown.md.

Using RCurl, I attempted:

```
## attempt 1
f <- paste(readLines('test-markdown.md'),collapse="\n" )
h <- dynCurlReader()
wp <- curlPerform(url="http://documentup.com/compiled", 
            postfields = c(content=f))
## attempt 2
postForm("http://documentup.com/compiled",
         "content" = fileUpload('test-markdown.md'))
```

Using httr, I tried:

```
## attempt 3
tmp <- POST("http://documentup.com/compiled", body = list(content= upload_file(f)))
content(tmp)

## attempt 4
tmp <- POST("http://documentup.com/compiled", body = list(content= upload_file("test-markdown.md")))
```

Comment: Is there a deeper reason you can't just use the R package `markdown` and/or work directly in RStudio?  Also, depending on the OS you use there is also `pandoc` ...

Comment: Have you seen the package `RCurl`? It has exactly what you need. Curl with options.

Comment: @Maiasaura - I didn't think to use RCurl, duh, but I have no idea as to how to set the options, especially since I need to reference a file.  Any tips?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - I love developing in Rstudio.  I saved the CSS locally and set the knitr options to reference the local stylesheet.  That didn't work perferectly.  I also attempted to do the same with Pandoc.  I like the layout that DocumentUp provides (the nav pane) and am hoping to retainn that for my markdown reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
library(httr)

url <- "http://documentup.com/compiled"
contents <- readLines("README.md")

resp <- POST(url, body = list(content = contents, name = "plyr"))
content(resp)
```

Comment: As always, Hadley you are the man.  Thank you for this!  I love this layout and it's great for handing off quick reports in HTML format.  Would love to see this service tied to Rstudio.  :)

Comment: @btibert3 what are the advantages of documentup compared to rpubs?

Comment: I really like the table of contents pane that is auto-generated based on headings.

Answer (score 1):

@Btibert3 Actually, you can tie it to RStudio yourself using the `rstudio.markdownToHTML` option. See http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering